# Slurm：Invalid qos specification

Tags: slurm

slurm created qos and assigned it to the user, but the user cannot use it.

- sacctmgr add qos test
- sacctmgr modify qos test set priority=10
- sacctmgr update qos test set MaxTRES=cpu=640
- sacctmgr modify user lei_wang set qos+=test

Invalid qos specification

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6E1V.png)

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjrjk.png)

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLTfF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
systemctl restart slurmctld
```